# What does the output of this plugin mean?

Tags: compression, ziparchive

I just tried to compress a file and am not sure if it worked or not.

The plugin I am using gave me the following results:

```
adding: wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/editimage.html (deflated 76%)
adding: wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/php.ini (deflated 64%)
adding: wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpdialogs/ (stored 0%)
```

The line I am concerned about is the third one:

```
wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpdialogs/  (stored 0%)
```

Can anyone explain what this means?

I think this could mean:

1. The file was not able to compress OR
2. The file was not able to get stored in part of the zip file OR
3. The original file was empty so there was nothing to compress

I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Three questions: What is the exact question here? What are you using to do the compression? How is this related to WordPress?

Comment: Could you check in your FTP client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into the Plugin code and then figuring out the PHP method used to create the zip archive you're better off just opening the file and checking the contents as @fdsa suggests.

The `stored 0%` would indicate there was nothing in the directory to add to the archive.

The `deflated xx%` indicates the percentage the file was compressed by adding it to the archive.